# Swagger mapping "on" to "true" when generating Java

Tags: swagger-codegen

I am using Swagger codegen 3.0.8 to generate Java files.  Part of the yaml spec is

```
PrepositionalPhrase:
  type: object
  required:
  - preposition
  - objects
  properties:
    preposition:
      description: The preposition
      type: string
      enum:
      - of
      - on
      - or
```

(with more values stripped for conciseness).  The generated enum is

```
  public enum PrepositionEnum {
    OF("of"),
    TRUE("true"),
    OR("or")
  }
```

For some reason, it appears that `on` is being mapped to `true`.  I can see that happening in some config parser, where "on" would logically mean "true", but that does not work for code generation.

The command line I am using to generate is

```
swagger-codegen generate            \
                -i api.yaml \
                -l java             \
                --api-package com.example \
                --artifact-version 1.2.0 \
                --artifact-id example \
                --group-id com.example \
                --model-package com.example.model
```

Is there some way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this ticket [swagger-codegen/issues/2559](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2559), it's rather a YAML format feature, which seems to be right:

```
Language Independent Scalar types:
    { ~, null }              : Null (no value).
    [ 1234, 0x4D2, 02333 ]   : [ Decimal int, Hexadecimal int, Octal int ]
    [ 1_230.15, 12.3015e+02 ]: [ Fixed float, Exponential float ]
    [ .inf, -.Inf, .NAN ]    : [ Infinity (float), Negative, Not a number ]
    { Y, true, Yes, ON  }    : Boolean true
    { n, FALSE, No, off }    : Boolean false
```

https://yaml.org/refcard.html

Apparently the workaround is to quote the values in the YAML file.

Comment: It's not a typo: I want the preposition (of), not the adjective (off)

Comment: @TroyDaniels Fair enough